# Redefined \cleardoublepage breaks line spacing

Tags: geometry, setspace, clearpage

I redefined the `\cleardoublepage` to show `This page is intentionally left blank` at the center of the page as follows:

```
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\newcommand{\blinkpagetext}{This page is intentionally left blank}
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\relax
    \clearpage
    \if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\relax\else
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newgeometry{centering}
    \null\vfill
    \centerline{\large\color{gray!20}\blinkpagetext}
    \vfill\restoregeometry\newpage\fi\fi}
```

However, the use of `\restoregeometry` will erase the effect of `\onehalfspacing` (provided by `setspace`) for the text follows. Is there any other way to achieve this effect of `\cleardoublepage` (without `tikz`, please), so that it doesn't interfere the effect of `setspace`?

Below is the complete code.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\newcommand{\blinkpagetext}{This page is intentionally left blank}
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\relax
    \clearpage
    \if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\relax\else
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newgeometry{centering}
    \null\vfill
    \centerline{\large\color{gray!20}\blinkpagetext}
    \vfill\restoregeometry\newpage\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing

\frontmatter
\blindtext

\mainmatter
\blindtext % these texts are not double-spaced

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a current LaTeX you can simply use the shipout hooks (with an older you can use eso-pic)

```
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\newcommand{\blinkpagetext}{This page is intentionally left blank}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\relax
    \clearpage
    \if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\relax\else
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \AddToHookNext{shipout/background}
      {% 
       \put(0.5\paperwidth,-0.5\paperheight){%
       \makebox[0pt]{\large\color{gray!20}\blinkpagetext}}}
    \null\newpage\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing

\frontmatter
\blindtext

\mainmatter
\blindtext %

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grouping.

I added `showframe` and changed the color to red just to produce a picture better showing the output.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\blinkpagetext}{This page is intentionally left blank}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
    \else
      \begingroup
      \newgeometry{centering}
      \thispagestyle{empty}
      \vspace*{\fill}
      \centerline{\large\color{red}\blinkpagetext}
      \vspace*{\fill}
      \clearpage
      \endgroup
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\doublespacing

\frontmatter
\blindtext

\mainmatter
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) has macros

```
\cleartoodpage[<text>]
\cleartoevenpage[<text>]
```

where `<text>`, if present, is put on the skipped page.